# Selenium SendKeys Keys.ArrowRight moves to end of contenteditable text

Tags: c#, selenium, .net-core, selenium-chromedriver

When I use `SendKeys` to send a right-hand-cursor-arrow, the caret moves to the end of the contenteditable instead of one character to the right.

- works as expected on input boxes
- used to work on previous versions (6 months ago, do not know versions)
- key event handlers report a right-arrow has been typed as expected
- versions

  - chrome: 78.0.3904.108
  - chrome driver: 78.0.3904.105
  - Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver: 77.0.0
  - Ubuntu 18.04

Here is sample unit test:

```cs
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;

namespace SeleniumTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class MiniTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            var driver = new ChromeDriver("/usr/bin", new ChromeOptions());

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("file:///home/daw/Desktop/test.html");

            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            var element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#test"));

            new Actions(driver)
                .MoveToElement(element, 1, 1)
                .Click()
                .Perform();

            driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement().SendKeys(Keys.ArrowRight);
        }
    }
}
```

And a sample page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test" contenteditable>This is a test</div>
        <input id="test2" value="This is a test"></input>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can change the `#test` id to switch between element types.

Edit: raised

- a selenium bug https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7841
- chromedriver bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3260

Comment: I am able to replicate your issue. I am on windows, using the same chrome and driver versions. I would guess that this is a bug on their end, which means that the only "solution" I can think of would be to downgrade temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

This has been identified as a chromedriver bug which is related to recent changes to the webdriver specification:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3214

> There is an open PR for the WebDriver spec; when that is approved, we will address this issue